# What is the minimum safe distance between two induction hobs/Stovetops?

Tags: kitchens, building-regulations

I am building a new kitchen in the UK and I want a 5-6 burner induction hob/stove.

However, a 5 or 6 burner induction hob is more than twice a 4 ring one. Given that I am looking at other options.

1. Install a 2 ring hob next to a 4 ring one
2. Suggestions?

Installing a 2 ring hob brings up regulation problems - as safe distance between appliances is 200mm.
Has anyone got any experience with navigating UK building regulations to figure this out?

IMO installing a hob next to another hob shouldn't require a 200mm gap.

Thanks

Comment: I can kinda guess what a "hob" is from context, But what does it actually stand for?  (Trying to learn more about "English" as I speak "American", LOL)

Comment: I'm guessing that "hob" is a UK word for "stove" or "cooktop".

Comment: Jwh20 is correct I had to ask a while back. I don’t know why any separation would be needed the induction is only on the surface “burner” area. If there needed to be a space one could not be next to many appliances or at least anything made of ferrous metal.

Comment: What do the instructions for the hobs you're looking at specify?

Comment: Could you say *which* Building Regulation states this 200mm distance?

Comment: Thanks all. Yes Hob is a stove in British English ... I am Australian, we call it a stove too.

Comment: @owain my builder is claiming this, I don't know which exact one, cannot find an actual regulation yet.

Comment: How close together are the "rings"  on a 4 ring one ?

Comment: Closest, maybe 75mm (2 inches)

Comment: Contact your local building department and ask them the question

Comment: The sparky is happy to install it with a 50mm gap, if any in the end :)

Comment: One thought is the supports in the benchtop - you might need to add a small cross-brace in your cabinetry to support the thin piece of benchtop between the two large holes for your hobs.  They won't support each other like a single large cooktop would, and you don't want it to sag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have now completed the build on this project.

The hobs/stove tops were installed with a 50mm gap by the sparky/ electrician.
Building control/ regulations certificate and safety certificates have been issued.

Therefore it is acceptable to all parties to install a hob with a 50mm gap.
We used a 900mm wide exhaust fan to cover both hobs.

See a photo:
[image: Picture of 2 hobs installed]

Comment: It's kind of tweaking my OCD a little, but a great looking kitchen! Congrats!

Comment: Thanks @GregNickoloff. You are going to have to explain how it "tweaks" your OCD?

Comment: Just kidding about the fact that there are 4 burners on one side and two on the other catches my eye. My daughter has me conditioned to needing perfect symmetry. It looks great. Really!

Comment: Thanks @GregNickoloff :)